# wp_insert_post running multiple times

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not very familiar with WordPress development, basically i have a separate PHP script that i wan't to be able to pass form data from it to a WP Plugin and the plugin will get that data via $_GET or so and insert it to WP as a new post.

I have tried the below code within the plugin which works, however causes errors regarding "called to undefined function is_user_loggedin".

```
$post = array(
            'post_title' => "test title",
            'post_content' => "test content",
            'post_date' => 0,
            'post_date_gmt' => 0,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_category' => array(1)
    );
wp_insert_post($post);
```

I then found a solution to this, wrap the code within a function and execute it with the "init" hook.

```
function insert_post(){
    $post = array(
            'post_title' => "test title",
            'post_content' => "test content",
            'post_date' => 0,
            'post_date_gmt' => 0,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_category' => array(1)
    );
    wp_insert_post($post);
}
add_action('init', 'insert_post');
```

Again, this inserts the post but it constantly keeps inserting the same post over and over rather than only inserting it once when my plugin is called.

Any help or solution to this would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: init runs literally every time wp is initiated. It's not the hook you're looking for.

Comment: Oh i see, it was an accepted answer to a question on here regarding the insert running multiple times so i assumed it was useful for this particular thing

Comment: Try using the `wp` hook instead of `init` as it runs quite a bit further down the order

Comment: @Und3rTow That still causes the issue of it inserting multiple times without being on the actual plugin URL, my goal is to only have it execute once when visiting the plugin URL

Comment: I see, you could potentially do a check using [`get_current_screen`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/) before inserting the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `wp_insert_post()` inside a function that is triggered by `save_post` action/hook... you will cause a loop because `save_post` will happen each time `wp_insert_post()` is processed.

You can set a "flag" so you can prevent it from looping.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post' );

function my_save_post( $post_id ) {
    
    if ( defined( 'INSERTING_POST' ) return;

    define( 'INSERTING_POST', true );

    $post = [
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
        'post_title'=> 'The Post Title Here',
        'post_content' => 'The post content here.'
    ];
    $inserted_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
    
    update_post_meta( $inserted_post_id, 'my_meta_key', 'my_meta_value' );
    // etc...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont use Wordpress. but When i look at the
[Wordpress WP Insert Post Guidance](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

You should not wrap the Code in Function.
Kindly re check Whether you have included all the required includes/required files to call the wp_insert

EX:

```
// Gather post data.
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'My post',
    'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
);
 
// Insert the post into the database.
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

that

> wp_insert_post() passes data through sanitize_post(), which itself handles all necessary sanitization and validation (kses, etc.).

according to the wordpress Guidance

Comment: Running it by itself causes the loggedin error because it's called first.before other things

Comment: it's not just about "not wrapping the Code in Function"... which i assume means "do not use the `wp_insert_post()` inside a function"... it specifically do not use the function inside a function that gets triggered by `save_post` hook... because it will cause a loop when the process of inserting the post triggers `save_post` hook endlessly